# JPQL work with LIKE statement and AND condition

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

may I ask my JPQL statement consist any error? Or the AND condition cannot work with LIKE statement?

```
public List searchByTime(String from, String to, String a){
 Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EnrollmentDetails e WHERE (e.startTime >= ?1 AND e.endTime <= ?2) AND (e.offerCode.offerCode LIKE: ?3)");
 q.setParameter(1,  from);
 q.setParameter(2,  to);
 q.setParameter(3,   a + "%");
  List l = q.getResultList();
  return l;
}
```

Whenever I remove `AND (e.offerCode.offerCode LIKE: ?3)` and 
 `q.setParameter(3,   a + "%");`, then the statement is work, but without the result what I want.

I'm pretty sure the 2 statements that I removed are correct as they work in other function.

Just in this function is not working. Can anyone help me.

thank you.

Comment: Why do you have "LIKE:"? The colon `:` will confuse some parsers thinking that a named parameter follows, besides that is illegal to have a colon there

Comment: Thank you at all, thanks for helping to debugging my error, I should take break to rest my eyes. Thank you. Haha....

Comment: @NeilStockton You should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a colon `:` just after the `LIKE` keyword which is illegal. A `:` can only be used as part of a named parameter. Remove that and it likely will work